# Why can't I deploy my Unlocked Package back in to my own Sandbox org?

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package

## The Background

We are a super-sized Performance Edition organization with a number of enhanced limits, and migrating our "happy soup" to DX Unlocked packages.

We previously had problems creating some of our Unlocked Packages, and eventually came up with a configuration file that allowed us to create these packages.

## The Configuration

Our config file used for all of the packages is as follows:

```
{
    "features": [
        "Communities",
        "StateAndCountryPicklist",
        "AddCustomRelationships:10",
        "AddHistoryFieldsPerEntity:25"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "accountSettings": {
            "enableAccountTeams": true
        },
        "orgPreferenceSettings": {
            "networksEnabled": true
        },
        "nameSettings": {
            "enableMiddleName": true,
            "enableNameSuffix": true
        }
    }
}
```

## The Problem

Now, we're trying to install these packages in to a Sandbox for testing purposes before we try to go live. The installer runs for about 5 minutes, then gives us the following installation error:

> ERROR: Encountered errors installing the package!,Installation errors:
>
> 1) Custom Relationship Limit Exceeded, Details: Cannot create new relationship. Each object can have no more than 40 custom relationships, including Master-Detail and Lookup relationships.

---

The sandbox we're attempting to install to is a copy from production that should have the same "extra custom relationships" settings as production itself. The metadata for this Unlocked Package includes all of the custom relationships we need to successfully deploy the remaining packages.

Is this a current limitation of Unlocked Packages? How is it we're allowed to create packages we cannot install? Do I need to remove one or more fields from my package and/or sandbox to get this to work? All the new features suggests that we should be able to do this without too much difficulty, but the docs are not clear on how to proceed.

## The Question

How do we, as a super-sized org, get our sandboxes and scratch orgs to work with our super-sized configuration Unlocked Packages?

---

## Edit

Apparently, our org limits were reduced? Here's our current org limits, both in the Sandbox and Production. I'll need to follow up with Support.

[image: Object Limits]

Comment: Posted it to Unlocked Packages group in Success with link back here so hopefully someone in the team can take a  look

Comment: @sfdcfox, are you able to deploy that in production but not in the sandbox which is a fresh copy of it?

Comment: @sfdcfox - the PM is asking for you to raise a case, and then update the thread in the chatter group with the case number...can you raise a case, and let me know the number, and I'll post it to the right place

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC Thanks. If you give me a link to the group or thread, I can update it there. I'm logging a case now.

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00004Wa61k?fromEmail=1&s1oid=00D300000000iTz&s1nid=0DB30000000072L&s1uid=00530000002ag5t&s1ext=0&emkind=chatterCommentNotification&emtm=1566361147346

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC done! Thanks for the assist!

Comment: @sfdcfox Maybe you have already done this but just to confirm: have you checked under the object limit section of the relevant object(s), to verify that the Custom Relationship Fields limit is really increased above 40 in that sandbox?

Comment: @Shamina Oh. My. Goodness. Looks like the mystery has been solved. Or, at least, *one* mystery has been solved. I'm not sure why the limits were reduced, but we appear to be over limits. I'm still going to have to see if there's a fix we can apply aside from increasing limits again, but at least I have more info now.

Comment: @sfdcfox :) so this explains the error then. Actually I had a doubt that this kind of limit increase gets copied automatically into sandbox from production. Seems to me that if the limit was increased in production, it has to be explicitly requested for all applicable sandboxes. but hope there is a fix to workaround this when deploying unlocked packages

Comment: Just to rule that one out: You have no existing "soft-deleted" relationships that may still be counted in the limit?
Some sneaky soft deletions may disturb you from time to time :) Find more on that here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244538/custom-relationship-field-limit-not-reflecting-deletes

Comment: @mlew Confirmed with support: our "extra" relationships were deprovisioned at some point in history, leaving us with 45/40 relationships. My manager has put in a request to have this value increased back to 45 so we can move forward. That said, I appreciate your help and everyone else that has chimed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is not a new sandbox, have you recently refreshed it?

If not, try and refresh/spawn a new one.  Sandboxes do not automatically get production changes, you need to refresh them.

You could also try matching production licenses as below if you can't refresh or spawn a new one:

> To match licenses, log in to your sandbox. From Setup, enter **Company
>   Informatio**n in the Quick Find box, select Company Information, and
>   then click **Match Production Licenses**. You get an alert when the
>   matching process starts. After all licenses have been matched in
>   sandbox, you get a confirmation email. The confirmation email is sent
>   to the user who initiates the license copy.

But certainly a refresh/new sandbox would be better as this "should" copy your exact production settings.

Comment: The question body states "The sandbox we're attempting to install to is a copy from production that should have the same "extra custom relationships" settings as production itself"

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I created a new sandbox yesterday, and tried ti again, same results.

Comment: @DavidReed, yeah, it says that it's an exact copy, but it didn't say when it was refreshed, to someone without much experience the refresh part might not be obvious and it never hurts to validate first.

Comment: I just saw this. I'm giving you the mark for this; what happened was Salesforce had reduced our limits in production, such that we actually had over 100% usage of lookups (some odd 140% or so), so Sandboxes were also broken. This was eventually fixed, and the packages install correctly now.